# I want to count the number of elements which are preceded by 0 but are greater than 10 and less than 20

Tags: arrays, matlab, counting

```
% counting the number of transitions from state 0 to 1,
% rain is an array of size 545.
    count1=0;
    n=numel(rain);
    for k=1:n-1,
        if (rain(k)<=0) & (10<rain(k+1)<20),
            count1=count1+1;
        end
    end
    display(count1)
    display(n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum(rain(2:end) > 10 & rain(2:end) < 20 & rain(1:end-1) = 0)
```

`rain(1:end-1)`: Get all the rain data bar the last element
`rain(2:end)`:   Get all the rain data bar the first element. The reason for this is to shift the data one element forward so that it's easy to search for a previous value of zero. (i.e. previous values are now in the same position as the values you want to check the limits for)

`rain > 10` will return a logical vector with `1`s where it is greater than 10 and `0`s otherwise. Calling `sum` on this just adds up all the `1`s so it proxies for counting them.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Can u please elaborate your code a bit? Why did you use 2:end as bounds and what does sum function return?

Comment: @DipankarChoudhary no problem, check my edit. This is best understood by executing each part of it separately in the command line on a subset of rain leaving off the semicolons so you can see what each part does.